# Paired, repeated-measures ANOVA or a mixed model?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, stata

I have been asked to analyse some data from a clinical trial looking a two methods of measuring blood pressure.  I have data from 50 subjects, each with between 2 and 57 measures using each method.

I'm wondering how best to proceed.

Obviously I need a solution that will account for the fact the measure of blood pressure is paired (two methods measured contemporaneously) and also a time varying covariate (with a varying number of observations per patient) as well as account for intra- and  inter-patient variablility.

I was thinking of somehow shoe-horning this into repeated measures ANOVA, but I'm thinking it might need to be a mixed model approch.

I'd appreciate any helpful advice you could offer.

I'm a complete R newbie but very excited to develop skills and I have a moderate experience in Stata so could always fall back on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do what you want to do with RM-ANOVA since number of the repetitions are not the same for all subjects. Running mixed-effects models is very easy in R. In fact, by investing a little time to learn the fundamentals and the commands, it will open a lot of possibilities to you. I also find mixed-modeling much simpler to use and more flexible and almost never need to do RM-ANOVA directly. Finally, consider that with mixed modeling you can also account for the covariance structure of the residuals (RM-ANOVA simply assumes a diagonal structure) which can be important for many applications.

There are two main packages for linear mixed modeling in R: `nlme` and `lme4`. The `lme4` packages is the more modern one which is great for large datasets and also for the cases you deal with clustered data. `Nlme` is the older package and is mostly deprecated in favor of `lme4`. However, for repeated measures designs it is still better than `lme4` since only `nlme` allows you to model the covariance structure of the residuals. The basic syntax of `nlme` is very simple. For example:

`fit.1 <- lme(dv ~ x + t, random=~1|subject, cor=corCompSymm())`

Here I'm modeling the relationship between a dependent variable `dv` and a factor `x` and time-related covariate `t`. `Subject` is a random effect and I have used a compound symmetry structure for the covariance of the residuals. Now you can easily get the infamous p-values by:

`anova(fit.1)`

Finally, I can suggest you to read more about nlme using its definitive reference guide, [Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989579). Another good reference for beginners is [Linear Mixed Models - a Practical Guide Using Statistical Software](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bwest/almmussp.html) which compiles lots of examples of different applications of mixed modeling with code in R, SAS, SPSS, etc.

Comment: another good introductory reference is [Gelman and Hill, Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)

Comment: Thanks Alef - those two references are awesome - as is Wolf's above.  I'm wondering if I can extend my question slightly in terms of how to structure the model.  I can't seem to identify the dv!!  I have two sets of BP measurement (two methods) as well as patient id and time of observation.  How can I model the difference between the two BP measurements (analogous to a one sample t-test that difference = 0)??  Sorry to hound you - I'll get on with my reading now!

Comment: Don't worry everyone - I think I've figured it out!!! I had my data in the wrong format.  When I finally figured out and manipulated it into long format, all of these posts made much more sense!!  Thanks again all.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It seems that as a general rule, most packages in R work with data in long format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for RM-ANOVA with mixed model by using R. You might want to check this out
http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/
There are great examples to demonstrate how to use mixed model to accomplish the RM-ANOVA.

Based on my experience, SAS is a better tool to deal with the mixed model. If you are using SAS, you could check the SAS help "Proc Mixed" for RM-ANOVA.